# Why is my app not detected in App store connect(after Xcode validate and upload)?

Tags: ios, xcode

I cloned my app from GitHub and followed all the steps in Xcode to build,archive,validate and upload app to App Store.

[image]

When I go to Apple developer  certificates identifiers & profiles

I can see my bundle ID

[image]

But in my App Store Connect, I can not find it. There are only apps from previous manual uploads.
[image]

After I press + button

My bundle ID is not detected.

[image]

Why?

Comment: There's a `+` button next to the `Apps` text, have you clicked it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create an app first by clicking the blue "+" on AppStore Connect. When asked for a Bundle ID, choose the bundle ID you will use with your builds.

[image]

Then the builds you upload will show under the "Testflight" tab.

[image]

It can take a few minutes to appear and a few more to be processed.

Comment: I am not sure about that I tried 5 times.

Comment: Take a look at my edit.

Comment: The probelm is it can not find my bundle id.

Comment: What should I check? My plist or ..?.